# CircleCI upload to Codecov is not working

Tags: circleci

I am using CircleCI with Cobertura and Codecov. But when I tried to upload the coverage report, I got this message.

```
->  Pinging Codecov
https://codecov.io/upload/v4?package=bash-20210309-2b87ace&token=secret&branch=main&commit=c4c31923a50262c49c578877bab7fee78a3781ff&build=81&build_url=&name=81&tag=&slug=TerabyteTB%2FWhirlpoolEditor&service=circleci&flags=&pr=&job=0&cmd_args=f,n,t
HTTP 400
Provided token is not a UUID.

400
```

Here is my config.yml file:

```yaml
version: 2.1

orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@1.1
  codecov: codecov/codecov@1.0.2
  
jobs:
  build:
    docker: 
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk-stretch
    steps: 
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Run tests
          command: mvn -f Editor/ clean install; mvn -f Editor cobertura:cobertura
      - codecov/upload:
          file: Editor/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
      
workflows:
  test:
    jobs:
      - build
```

Comment: `...&token=secret&...` - `"secret"` is indeed not a UUID. Look at e.g. https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/codecov/codecov to see how to configure the command - have you set the `CODECOV_TOKEN` environment variable?

Comment: Actually, I edited added it just now and it’s working. Thanks! What’s weird though is that Codecov says that it doesn’t need a token for circleci

Answer (score 0):

Although the Codecov document says upload token not required for Circle CI, it asks for token information.

You can set the token that Codevoc gives you under codecov/upload like this.

```
- codecov/upload:
         file: Editor/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
         **token: YOUR_TOKEN_INFO**
```